# How to remove entries in masks using Python and Image processing?

Tags: python, image, computer-vision

I'm currently working with masks of lung CTs.
The example shown below is an example of a mask. I would like to remove the entry in the image, a kind of an edge hole. How can I do this using Python/OpenCV or something else?

[image: Lung mask]

Comment: “Is there a way?” The answer is “yes”. I think you mean to ask “How to remove...?”. You should always be explicit about your questions on Stack Overflow, and elsewhere too. Also, why are you putting words in quotes? Quotes are for quoting things others said. Or they can be [scare quotes](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scare_quotes). Neither applies to invagination or edge hole.

Comment: One approach is to find the contour as a polygon, find its convex hull, then identify the deficiencies (where the convex hull and original polygon differ) that are small enough, and remove them. (Nog writing an answer because I can’t show code atm).